# scala printing word length histogram [Extra]

Tags: scala

How to modify this code

```
package main

object Main extends App {
  val lines = scala.io.Source.stdin.getLines //input the sentences, use "Enter" key for both changing line and end
  val words = lines.flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
  val list2 = words.toVector.groupBy(_.length).mapValues(_.length)
  val vectorOfLengths = (1 to list2.keys.max).map(length => list2.getOrElse(length, 0))
  for ((count, length) <- vectorOfLengths.zipWithIndex)
    println(f"${length+1} ${count} ${"*" * count}")
```

to realize the two goals:

1. flush-right align the numbers of words of each length
2. scale the length of the histogram bars so that the longest bar uses up the entire current width of the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You need to add the formatting portion to the interpolated string.  That would be `%2s` if you wanted two characters of space.

```
${length + 1}%2s
```

Second, You'll need to scale each `count` according to how big it is proportional to the longest bar:

```
val consoleWidth = 100
val maxCount = vectorOfLengths.max
for ((count, length) <- vectorOfLengths.zipWithIndex)
  println(f"${length + 1}%2s: ${"#" * (count * consoleWidth / maxCount)}")
```